# GCS on Google Cloud Functions slower than localhost

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a file in Google Cloud Storage. I need to access it from a Google Cloud Function that uses it to respond to an http request.

The code runs like a charm with "functions framework" on my PC and retrieves the file in about half a second.

When I put the code on Google Cloud Functions in the same region as the storage, I expected it to run faster (at least saving the network trip from my house in Milan to Google's locations in Belgium).To my surprise the same code running on GCF takes on average around **5** seconds (sometimes much longer).

I tried everything I could imagine without any significant effect.
Some things I already tried:

- changing the version of Node runtime
- importing fast-crc32c dependency
- requesting a ReadableStream and piping it directly to the res object

Now I am running out of ideas...

The relevant code is (simplified for testing and for clarity):

```
const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");

exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  const storage = new Storage({ projectId: "my project ID" });
  const bucketName = "my-bucket-name";
  const srcFilename = "my-file-name.json";

  let file = storage.bucket(bucketName).file(srcFilename);
  file
    .download()
    .then(function(data) {
      const d = data;
    })
    .then(() => {
      res.status(200).send("Ciao!");
    });
};
```

Any help or idea is much appreciated!

Thanks,

Filippo

---

PS I add an instrumented version of the code I used to measure the timing:

```
const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");

exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  var hrstart = process.hrtime();
  var timedEvents = [];
  function addTimedEvent(msg) {
    const event = { msg: msg, hrend: process.hrtime(hrstart) };
    timedEvents = [...timedEvents, event];
  }
  function printTimeEvents() {
    for (var e of timedEvents) {
      console.info(
        "Execution time (hr): %ds %dms Message:%s",
        e.hrend[0],
        e.hrend[1] / 1000000,
        e.msg
      );
    }
  }
  addTimedEvent("gcs 1");
  const storage = new Storage({ projectId: "my project ID" });
  const bucketName = "my-bucket-name";
  const srcFilename = "my-file-name.json";

  addTimedEvent("gcs 2");
  let file = storage.bucket(bucketName).file(srcFilename);
  addTimedEvent("gcs 3");
  file
    .download()
    .then(function(data) {
      addTimedEvent("gcs 4");
      const d = data;
      addTimedEvent("gcs 5");
    })
    .then(() => {
      printTimeEvents();
      res.status(200).send("Ciao world!");
    });
};
```

The typical execution on my PC:

```
Execution time (hr): 0s 0.0059ms Message:gcs 1
Execution time (hr): 0s 0.1911ms Message:gcs 2
Execution time (hr): 0s 0.7464ms Message:gcs 3
Execution time (hr): 0s 338.6312ms Message:gcs 4
Execution time (hr): 0s 338.6361ms Message:gcs 5
```

The typical execution on GCF:
[image: GCF logs]

Comment: Is it slow on every invocation or just the first?  Cloud functions endure a [cold start](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips) penalty if a new instance needs to be created to serve a request (frequently immediately after deployment, for example).

Comment: @robsiemb: on every invocation. To be sure, I measured the timing of the `file.download()` in order to sterilize any effect of the cold-start, but no... it is not a cold-start problem unfortunately.

Comment: Please edit the question show exactly what you're using to benchmark the time.  If you're not doing it in the code itself, you're probably measuring much more than just the transfer itself.

Comment: @DougStevenson I added the instrumented code, I hope it helps

Comment: Does your metrics match the ones on stackdriver Monitoring?

Comment: Yes, e.g. in the screenshot above you can see the stackdriver tells that the whole function takes 6.2s and I measure 5.9s spent reading the file from GCS. The code accumulates "execution time" messages in an array and prints them out at once at the end of the function.

Comment: I meant stackdirver monitoring [execution time own logging](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-cloudfunctions) this is monitored directly from GCP own servers and are more accurate than code logging.

Comment: Almost two years later and still the same issue... did you find a fix? @filippopanelli

Answer (score 1):

Set up whatever can be shared between invocations outside of the function, for example (if the bucket does not change):

```
const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");
const storage = new Storage({ projectId: "my project ID" });
const bucketName = "my-bucket-name";
const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);

exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  const srcFilename = "my-file-name.json";

  let file = bucket.file(srcFilename);
  file
    .download()
    .then(function(data) {
      const d = data;
    })
    .then(() => {
      res.status(200).send("Ciao!");
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jak for your suggestion. I did what you suggest and put as much as I could in static cons.
It helped somewhat, especially when I set maximum instances to 1 in order to reduce cold starts.
Now I get 5s on cold starts and 2s, 2.5s, 3s on following invocations. 

Unfortunately that is still much longer than what I get on my PC which is 0.4s, 0.6s, 0.8s.
I am not sure if there is anything more I can try,

Thanks a lot.
Filippo